# Get null values from map

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

```
//map to store attachments against categories
        for(MyDocument__c mdobj :[SELECT id,Category__c FROM MyDocument__c where id =:accObj.id]){

            for(Attachment attobj :[SELECT Id, Name, Description FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = :mdobj.Id]){
                if(!catAttMap.containsKey(mdobj.category__c)){
                catAttMap.put(mdobj.Category__c, new list<Attachment>());
                }
                catAttMap.get(mdobj.Category__c).add(attobj);    
            }
        }

        system.debug('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'+ catAttMap);
```

Comment: Just an aside - please do not use Salesforce-crm tag as this site is Salesforce Stack Exchange so everything here is about Salesforce. Thanks.

Comment: Ok..I will follow Dave..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would be more optimized solution:

```
for(MyDocument__c mdobj :[SELECT id,Category__c,(SELECT Id, Name, Description FROM Attachment) FROM MyDocument__c where id =:accObj.id]){

    if(!catAttMap.containsKey(mdobj.category__c)){
        if(mdObj.attachments.size()>0){
            catAttMap.get(mdobj.Category__c).add(mdobj.attachments);    
        }
        else{
            catAttMap.put(mdobj.Category__c, new list<Attachment>());
        }
    }
}
```

Here i have removed your query on attachment object.Instead i am doing it inside the parent query as inner query.

Now i can access all the related child of given custom object record by `mdobj.attachments`.Then inside loop i'm checking if there is any attachment with that record then include it inside map otherwise put a blank reference.Now if you want to retrieve keys whose attachment list is blank you can use following code:

```
//Assuming Category__c is a lookup
for(Id categoryId : catAttMap.keyset()){
    if(catAttMap.get(categoryId).size()==0){
         System.debug('this category has zero attachment'+categoryId );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the wonderful explaination..

Comment: And category__c is just a input picklist field..